# place images in a common place for android and ios in ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, react-native

wanna ask if there is a way to let Android and iOS share image assets in one place instead of placing them repeatedly in each folder, for React native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 0.14.0, which is the most current release (as of an hour ago), there is now a common asset system you can use for both Android and iOS. This is thanks to [@frantic's PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/3545)...

[The documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#content) doesn't seem to be updated yet, but this is well [documented in the PR itself](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/3545).

[image]